# Issues running selenium tests on MicrosoftEdge browser

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

Version: Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0
Microsoft Edge Driver Version: Version: 3.14393 | Edge version supported: 14.14393

While trying to run selenium tests, I am facing issues with
1. Link text
2. text control inputs
3. alertbox recognition
4. setting control to frame content
5. MultiSelect control, where only one of the items are selected
6. Assertions, the data that is being rendered on Edge vis a vis chrome/firefox are different.
7. File download, import in this case I am unable to set the DesiredCapabilities of the edge browser.